# Angular error: Can't bind to 'x property' since it isn't a known property of 'x element' , even after putting @Input in child component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have used an @Input decorator in a component to receive data from another component.

childComponent.ts-
`@Input() isShown: boolean;`

parentComponent.html-
`<tab [isShown]="form.get('tab').value === View.Account" [label]="Tab Name" ></tab>`

I am getting this error on compilation--
error: Can't bind to 'isShown' since it isn't a known property of 'tab'

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Maybe because you have two equal signs ? [isShown]== and it causes compilation errors.

Comment: That was a typo that I made here. Fixed it now. The error still persists. :(

Comment: is child component selector is tab?

Comment: Also, be sure that components are all correctly declared inside your module declarations / exports.

Comment: No, child component has different selector. The <tab> in the html is for a tab  element coming from a custom library.

Comment: @RicardoMachado yes, they seem to be declared correctly.

Comment: Try to add FormsModule into your module too. Other way, try to reproduce it in an angular sandbox online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the above comments and see that "tab" selector being a selector for a custom library, not your child component, it doesn't make any sense of having an `@Input` on your child, but you use it to another component.
The `isShown` should be used with the child selector.